# Vagrant public network can ping but cant get response from apache server

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I configured vagrant with virtualbox with the given Vagrantfile settings below. I can connect to web server running on the virtual machine from the host machine (HM).

I also can ping to the server from a network machine, but when I try to access the web server from network, the Virtual machine(VM) gets the request and says it responds (apache), but the network machine (NM) does not get the response.

How should I configure vagrant or virtualbox to access from NM? I tried changing eth1's to eth0 on the VM interfaces file , but it didnt work. Vagrant cant up the machine.

Thanks in advance

Vagrantfile:

```rb
config.vm.define "web" do |web|
  web.vm.box = "raring"
  web.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.0.53", bridge: 'eth0'
  web.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 1024]
  end
end
```

Host machine interface

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:04:a6:68:7d:85  
      inet addr:192.168.0.102  Bcast:255.255.255.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:576  Metric:1
      RX packets:142100 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:110704 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:61653460 (61.6 MB)  TX bytes:14976111 (14.9 MB)
      Interrupt:55 Base address:0xa000
```

Virtual machine interface

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:49:4c:f1  
      inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe49:4cf1/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:386 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:276 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:41117 (41.1 KB)  TX bytes:36296 (36.2 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:c3:16:90  
      inet addr:192.168.0.53  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fec3:1690/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:946 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1017 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:116117 (116.1 KB)  TX bytes:90515 (90.5 KB)
```

virtual machine /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
#VAGRANT-BEGIN
# The contents below are automatically generated by Vagrant. Do not     modify.
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
  address 192.168.0.53
  netmask 255.255.255.0
#VAGRANT-END
```

apache response on the VM:

```
192.168.0.100 - - [16/Nov/2013:10:39:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" "curl/7.32.0" 200 7466 6005
```

Comment: Can you post the verbose output of curl? (`curl -v ...`)

Comment: Did you manage to get it working? I have the same issue.

Comment: Same issue on Windows with Ubuntu 14.04 as the base box

Answer (score 0):

This problem comes up not from vagrant or vagrant setup, but because of bad apache configuration in virtual machine (VM).

Modify yours apache site configuration in the VM:

`vim /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/yours_site_config.conf`

Change a server name to: `ServerName 192.168.0.53`

After restarting apache check the results in your browser.

E.g.:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin servers@localhost
    ServerName 192.168.0.53
    DocumentRoot /var/www
 </VirtualHost>`

192.168.0.53 - this is an inet addr of yours VM.